# Syntax error using a leading parenthesis with insert into

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, insert, union, parentheses

The left paren directly after the "into @gutsTVP" breaks this.
The error is on the right paren on line 12.
If remove that first set of parens around the first union it runs but it returns the wrong answer as then the intersect is applied before the first union

```
DECLARE @gutsTVP AS TABLE ( sID INT PRIMARY KEY); 
insert into @gutsTVP
(
        select distinct [ftsIndexWordOnce].[sID] 
        from [ftsIndexWordOnce] with (nolock)
        where [ftsIndexWordOnce].[wordID] in (1,2)
    union
        select distinct [ftsIndexWordOnceB].[sID] 
        from [ftsIndexWordOnceB] with (nolock)
        where [ftsIndexWordOnceB].[wordID] in (5,6)
)
intersect
(
        select distinct [ftsIndexWordOnce].[sID] 
        from [ftsIndexWordOnce] with (nolock)   
        where [ftsIndexWordOnce].[wordID] in (9,10,11,12)
    union
        select distinct [ftsIndexWordOnceB].[sID] 
        from [ftsIndexWordOnceB] with (nolock)  
        where [ftsIndexWordOnceB].[wordID] in (13,14,15,16)
)
select [guts].[sID] from @gutsTVP as [guts] 
join [docSVsys] with (nolock)
  on [docSVsys].[sID] = [guts].[sID]
order by [docSVsys].[sParID], [docSVsys].[sID]
```

Included the final join as that is the purpose of the TABLE.
If I join on a derived table it is not aware of  PK and much much slower.

Yes I am aware could re-factor this to not have a leading left paren.
This is a simplified query.
Need to be able to handle a leading left paren.

Below tricks the syntax into working.
But now the join is slower as it is not aware of a PK.
Cannot have sID as PK and accept null

```
DECLARE @gutsTVP AS TABLE ( sID INT PRIMARY KEY); 
insert into @gutsTVP
select 0  -- real PK starts at 1
union
(     
        select distinct [ftsIndexWordOnce].[sID] 
        from [ftsIndexWordOnce] with (nolock)
        where [ftsIndexWordOnce].[wordID] in (1,2)
    union
        select distinct [ftsIndexWordOnceB].[sID] 
        from [ftsIndexWordOnceB] with (nolock)
        where [ftsIndexWordOnceB].[wordID] in (5,6)
)
intersect
(
        select distinct [ftsIndexWordOnce].[sID] 
        from [ftsIndexWordOnce] with (nolock)   
        where [ftsIndexWordOnce].[wordID] in (9,10,11,12)
    union
        select distinct [ftsIndexWordOnceB].[sID] 
        from [ftsIndexWordOnceB] with (nolock)  
        where [ftsIndexWordOnceB].[wordID] in (13,14,15,16)
)
select [guts].[sID] from  @gutsTVP as [guts]
join [docSVsys] with (nolock)
  on [docSVsys].[sID] = [guts].[sID]
where [guts].[sID] > 0
order by [docSVsys].[sParID], [docSVsys].[sID]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try CTEs instead:

```
DECLARE @gutsTVP AS TABLE ( sID INT PRIMARY KEY); 
; WITH a AS (
        select [ftsIndexWordOnce].[sID] 
        from [ftsIndexWordOnce] with (nolock)
        where [ftsIndexWordOnce].[wordID] in (1,2)
    union
        select [ftsIndexWordOnceB].[sID] 
        from [ftsIndexWordOnceB] with (nolock)
        where [ftsIndexWordOnceB].[wordID] in (5,6)
)
, b AS (
        select [ftsIndexWordOnce].[sID] 
        from [ftsIndexWordOnce] with (nolock)   
        where [ftsIndexWordOnce].[wordID] in (9,10,11,12)
    union
        select [ftsIndexWordOnceB].[sID] 
        from [ftsIndexWordOnceB] with (nolock)  
        where [ftsIndexWordOnceB].[wordID] in (13,14,15,16)
)
insert into @gutsTVP
SELECT * FROM a
    intersect
SELECT * FROM b;

select [guts].[sID] from @gutsTVP as [guts] 
join [docSVsys] with (nolock)
  on [docSVsys].[sID] = [guts].[sID]
order by [docSVsys].[sParID], [docSVsys].[sID]
```

Also note that you can discard the `distinct`s since they are already implied by the `union`s.

Comment: I could remove the distinct but it runs significantly slower with - really.   This works +1 but I want to build up that syntax in a linear manner.   I updated my work around.

Comment: Looks good. The parens are a little tricky - without the INSERT your original query becomes syntactically correct. But when an opening paren immediately follows an INSERT, SQL Server expects a column list rather than a set of values.

Comment: On further testing this performs better than my hack

Comment: And did not need to break it up into a, b.  Was able to just pack it all in a single cte.